# how to set source for for a foreign key in serializer django rest frame work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model, serialization

i have model as follows:

```
class UserWorkspace(models.Model):
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(
        "Workspace", models.CASCADE, db_column="workspace_uuid"
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", models.CASCADE, db_column="user_uuid")
```

and i need to change the name in serializer i tried:

```
class UserWorkspaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workspace_uuid = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="workspace", queryset=Workspace.objects.all())
    user_uuid = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="user", queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = UserWorkspace
        fields = ("workspace_uuid", "user_uuid")
```

but i get the error

```
    return self.fields[key]
KeyError: 'workspace'
```

Answer (score -1):

change your code like this

```
workspace = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="workspace_uuid", queryset=Workspace.objects.all())
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="user_uuid", queryset=User.objects.all())
```

[Source Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: this does not work this is no different that removing these two lines

Comment: This answer does not provide any explanation whatsoever. Providing the documentation's link without helping to understand it and how it translates in this specific case does not constitue a solution and does not help continue debugging further.